# I am a complete beginner and need some guidance on where to start

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, github

I am completely new and haven't ever coded anything. I want to learn how but am not sure what the best option is. I have Atom for coding and also downloaded visual studio, but have no idea what to do from there. I know that I can get stuff from github for example, but am not really sure what to do, or how to modify or contribute to anything or opensource code. is there a tutorial or something that i can use to follow?

got github, Atom, and visual studio.

Comment: Your question is off-topic for this site, and you may not be completely clear on how to best use this site. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [ask] a good question sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get a better reception from site members and perhaps decent answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there and welcome to the community.
For what you are looking to do, you should pick a programming language (if you like web development you should try to learn the basics and pick up a web framework such as Angular, if you like software development maybe try C# or C++) and play with it from there. I can't give you a definite answer in where specifically to start but play around with things to see what you are interested in doing.

Regarding putting code up on GitHub you are able to do private and public repositories. The private ones are accessible to you and the people you share them with (on the freemium model of Github you can only get a few people on the private repos when not paying for pro). The public repositories come up in search results and you can contribute to other public repositories, create your own, or both. (Repositories contain projects/code-snippets that people are wanting to share).